# How to disable mouse clicks in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

### Trying To achieve

I'm trying to block input from mouse for certain time

I want to use the code like this: -

```
BlockMouse(true);

// My code starts here
...
// My code ends here

BlockMouse(false);
```

### I Tried

- `BlockInput(true)` but it requires elevated permissions

Comment: Look at a lowlevel mouse hook.

Comment: I don't have any idea about lowlevel mouse and how to cancel the mouse click events

Comment: Perhaps you should explain a bit about why you want to do this. There might be a more straight-forward way to achieve the same overall effect.

Comment: @Jquey007 Maybe that is something worth looking into... Also this has been asked before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524608/how-can-i-disable-mouse-click-event-system-wide-using-c

Comment: okay my app sends info to other application in the end it is send Enter button event which is disturbing by mouse clicks

Comment: Is it WPF or WinForm?

Answer (score 2):

Use this code and implement IMessageFilter aswell

```
Rectangle BoundRect;
Rectangle OldRect = Rectangle.Empty;

private void EnableMouse()
{
    Cursor.Clip = OldRect;
    Cursor.Show();
    Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
}
public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == 0x201 || m.Msg == 0x202 || m.Msg == 0x203) return true;
    if (m.Msg == 0x204 || m.Msg == 0x205 || m.Msg == 0x206) return true;
    return false;
}
private void DisableMouse()
{
    OldRect = Cursor.Clip;
    // Arbitrary location.
    BoundRect = new Rectangle(50, 50, 1, 1); 
    Cursor.Clip = BoundRect;
    Cursor.Hide();
    Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is more elegant to set all your controls (like button) to disabled for the time your code is running and then enable them again

To give the user an optical feedback set the cursor to busy with `Application.UseWaitCursor = true;` and then `Application.UseWaitCursor = false;`

of course this solution only blocks the mouse clicks on your application and does not disable the mouse clicks completely

Comment: This is a nice solution but he never says he only wants to stop clicks on his program, so if he wants to stop all mouse clicks system wide this no longer works.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it is good to block mouse click because most of the inputs are by mouse click, it is better if you rewrite `protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)`